# NetBeans 8.2 Do not see the option to create a Java Application

Tags: java, netbeans

This is what pops up

[image: This is what pops up]

We recently started coding with Java in class a few days ago so I'm very new to it. My teacher told us we were able to get Netbeans IDE 8.2 (version we use in school) at home. This was true, however I do not see the option to create a "Java Application" when trying to create a new project. All I see is "Java Free-Form Project." Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Which [Netbeans distribution](https://netbeans.org/downloads/8.2/) did you download?

Comment: I guess I'm not entirely sure, I just downloaded it from here. (WIndows 64 version) https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-3413139-esa.html

Comment: The old netbeans site used to have several versions of NetBeans, like one for just Java, and one for JEE, and one for developing in other laguages  like JavaScript or PHP.  You seem to have got the "blank" one.  You may have to install modules to get your copy to do anything.

Comment: P.S. NetBeans 10 is an Apache Incubator project.  You might want to get the latest instead of 8.2.  https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html

Comment: OK, re. my comment on "install modules", I think what you're looking for is Tools => Plugins.  Go to that menu, and check which plug-ins you have already.  If JAVA SE isn't there, that's the issue.

Comment: @markspace thanks a lot, your solution ended up working. Sosrry if I seem kinda stupid, im very new to this lmao